# annulus with scipy Delaunay

Tags: scipy, python-3.6, delaunay

i try to draw a 3d solid that represents an annulus. I have used the scipy module and Delaunay to do the calculation.
Unfortunately the plot shows a 3d cylinder and not an annulus. Has somebody an idea how to modify the code? Is scipy the right module? Can i use Delaunay with retangular shapes?
thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

points = 50

theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,points)
radius_middle = 7.5
radius_inner = 7
radius_outer = 8

x_m_cartesian = radius_middle * np.cos(theta)
y_m_cartesian = radius_middle * np.sin(theta)
z_m_cartesian = np.zeros(points)
M_m = np.c_[x_m_cartesian,y_m_cartesian,z_m_cartesian]

x_i_cartesian = radius_inner * np.cos(theta)
y_i_cartesian = radius_inner * np.sin(theta)
z_i_cartesian = np.zeros(points)
M_i = np.c_[x_i_cartesian,y_i_cartesian,z_i_cartesian]

x1_m_cartesian = radius_middle * np.cos(theta)
y1_m_cartesian = radius_middle * np.sin(theta)
z1_m_cartesian = np.ones(points)
M1_m = np.c_[x1_m_cartesian,y1_m_cartesian,z1_m_cartesian]

x2_i_cartesian = radius_inner * np.cos(theta)
y2_i_cartesian = radius_inner * np.sin(theta)
z2_i_cartesian = np.ones(points)
M2_i = np.c_[x2_i_cartesian,y2_i_cartesian,z2_i_cartesian]

M = np.vstack((M_m,M_i,M1_m,M2_i))

# Delaunay
CH = Delaunay(M).convex_hull

x,y,z = M[:,0],M[:,1],M[:,2]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
#ax.scatter(x[:,0],y[:,1],z[:,2])
ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=CH, shade=False, color='lightblue',lw=1, edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The `convex_hull` of a ring of points is whole disk, not an annulus.   There may be a way of 'subtracting' the inner disk, but the basic *convex* shape does not have holes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you propose an other tool/module to create annulus. Subtracting the inner ring is not possible with convex_hull...

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the convex hull is a convex shape and therefore cannot represent an annulus. However, the concept of the `concave hull` (also known as the `alpha-shape`) is probably appropriate for your needs. Basically, the alpha-shape removes from the Delaunay triangulation the triangles (tetrahedra in your 3D case) that have a circumradius greater than some value (defined by the `alpha` parameter).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58113037/9702190) provides an implementation of the alpha-shape surface (i.e., the outer boundary) for 3D points. Using the `alpha_shape_3D` function from that answer, with an alpha value of 3, resulted in the figure below.

The following two lines in the code (replacing the assignment to `CH` and the plot function) do the job.

```
vertices, edges, facets = alpha_shape_3D(pos=M, alpha=3.)

ax.plot_trisurf(x,y,z,triangles=facets, shade=False, color='lightblue',lw=1, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]