# Alpha Shapes in 3D - Follow Up

Tags: python, matplotlib, concave-hull, pyvista, alpha-shape

#### Problem

---

I am trying to implement Edelsbrunner's Algorithm for the alpha shape of a 3D point cloud in python as presented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303878/alpha-shapes-in-3d). However, I'm having trouble plotting results. Half my sphere looks good, and the other half garbled.

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that I have negative coordinates, but I'm not sure.

---

#### Definitions

---

I'm adding these so programmers can contribute without being bogged down by math. These are simplified definitions and not meant to be precise (Feel free to skip this part; for more, see see [Introduction to Alpha Shapes](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-11-spring/handouts/AlphaShapes/as_fisher.pdf) and [Discrete Differential Geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mas-PUA3OvA)):

- **Delaunay triangulation:** *for a 2D point set, a tesselation of the points into triangles (i.e. "triangulation") where the circumscribed circle (i.e. "circumcircle") about every triangle contains no other points in the set. For 3D points, replace "triangle" with "tetrahedron" and "circumcircle" with "circumsphere".*
- **Affinely independent:** *a collection of points `p0, ..., pk` such that all vectors `vi := pi-p0` are linearly independent (i.e. in 2D not collinear, in 3D not coplanar); also called "points in general position"*
- **k-simplex:** *the convex hull of k+1 affinely-independent points; we call the points its vertices.*

> 0-simplex = point *(consists of 0+1 = 1 points)*
> 1-simplex = line *(consists of 1+1 = 2 points)*
> 2-simplex = triangle *(consists of 2+1 = 3 points)*
> 3-simplex = tetrahedron *(consists of 3+1 = 4 points)*

- **face:** *any simplex whose vertices are a subset of the vertices of another simplex; i.e. "a part of a simplex"*
- **(geometric) simplicial complex:** *a collection of simplices where (1) the intersection of two simplices is a simplex, and (2) every face of a simplex is in the complex; i.e. "a bunch of simplices"*
- **alpha-exposed:** *a simplex within a point set where the circle (2D) or ball (3D) of radius alpha through its vertices doesn't contain any other point in the point set*
- **alpha shape:** *the boundary of all alpha-exposed simplices of a point set*

#### Algorithm

---

Edelsbrunner's Algorithm is as follows:

> Given a point cloud `pts`:
>
> 1. Compute the Delaunay triangulation `DT` of the point cloud
> 2. Find the alpha-complex: search all simplices in the Delaunay triangulation and    (a) if any ball around a simplex is empty and has
>    a radius less than `alpha` (called the "alpha test"), then add it to the
>    alpha complex
> 3. The boundary of the alpha complex is the alpha shape

#### Code

---

```py
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyvista as pv

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

plotter = pv.Plotter()

def alpha_shape_3D(pos, alpha):
    """
    Compute the alpha shape (concave hull) of a set of 3D points.
    Parameters:
        pos - np.array of shape (n,3) points.
        alpha - alpha value.
    return
        outer surface vertex indices, edge indices, and triangle indices
    """

    tetra = Delaunay(pos)
    # Find radius of the circumsphere.
    # By definition, radius of the sphere fitting inside the tetrahedral needs 
    # to be smaller than alpha value
    # http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html
    tetrapos = np.take(pos,tetra.vertices,axis=0)
    normsq = np.sum(tetrapos**2,axis=2)[:,:,None]
    ones = np.ones((tetrapos.shape[0],tetrapos.shape[1],1))
    a = np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((tetrapos,ones),axis=2))
    Dx = np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((normsq,tetrapos[:,:,[1,2]],ones),axis=2))
    Dy = -np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((normsq,tetrapos[:,:,[0,2]],ones),axis=2))
    Dz = np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((normsq,tetrapos[:,:,[0,1]],ones),axis=2))
    c = np.linalg.det(np.concatenate((normsq,tetrapos),axis=2))
    r = np.sqrt(Dx**2+Dy**2+Dz**2-4*a*c)/(2*np.abs(a))

    # Find tetrahedrals
    tetras = tetra.vertices[r<alpha,:]
    # triangles
    TriComb = np.array([(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)])
    Triangles = tetras[:,TriComb].reshape(-1,3)
    Triangles = np.sort(Triangles,axis=1)
    # Remove triangles that occurs twice, because they are within shapes
    TrianglesDict = defaultdict(int)
    for tri in Triangles:TrianglesDict[tuple(tri)] += 1
    Triangles=np.array([tri for tri in TrianglesDict if TrianglesDict[tri] ==1])
    #edges
    EdgeComb=np.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)])
    Edges=Triangles[:,EdgeComb].reshape(-1,2)
    Edges=np.sort(Edges,axis=1)
    Edges=np.unique(Edges,axis=0)

    Vertices = np.unique(Edges)
    return Vertices,Edges,Triangles

def ptcloud_sphere():
    r = 3
    phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 18)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 36)

    PHI, THETA = np.meshgrid(phi, theta)

    x = r * np.sin(PHI) * np.cos(THETA)
    y = r * np.sin(PHI) * np.sin(THETA)
    z = r * np.cos(PHI)

    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
    plt.show()
    
    pts = np.stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()), axis=1)

    return np.unique(pts, axis=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pts = ptcloud_sphere()

    verts, edges, faces = alpha_shape_3D(pts, alpha=10)

    faces_conn_list = np.insert(faces, 0, 3, axis=1)
    num_faces = faces.shape[0]

    mesh = pv.PolyData(pts[verts], faces_conn_list, n_faces=num_faces)

    plotter.add_mesh(mesh, reset_camera=True)
    plotter.show()
```

#### Output

**Point Cloud:**

[image: Point Cloud]

**Alpha Shape:**

[image: Alpha Shape]

#### Update 09-SEP-2021

Per @akaszynski, the problem does indeed appear to be a combination of unique and negative points. He fixed this issue with the following:

```py
pts = np.stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()), axis=1) + 10

return np.unique(pts, axis=0) - 10
```

[image: Fixed Sphere]

However, if someone could perform a deeper investigation to determine why this is the problem, that would help.

#### Update 09-SEP-2021 #2

Per @AndrasDeak, both `pyvista` and `VTK` support the creation of 2d and 3d alpha shapes. The `pyvista` function `delaunay_3d` uses `vtkDelaunay3D` under the hood, which accepts an `alpha` parameter.

(See [vtkDelaunay3D docs](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDelaunay3D.html))

Comment: @AndrasDeak Can you help?

Comment: You can't really ping me like that, but I'm watching pyvista questions anyway. Did you check that the `Delaunay` step does what you expect it to do? (Side note: you can also do Delaunay-triangulation with pyvista, and create the sphere point cloud with `pv.Sphere().points`.) Triangulation can be tricky with point clouds. For instance `pv.Sphere().delaunay_2d()` only gives you half a sphere, and `pv.Sphere().delaunay_3d()` gives you triangles all over the place. But if it's a valid triangulation then the algorithm could still work with it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Oh, hahaha! I thought I could. Sorry. Alex was able to confirm the issue does have to do with unique and negative points, but we still haven't figured out why this is the case. I added an update to my question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Good point too! I didn't know you could do alpha shapes in vtk! I'll put that in the update as well.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Can `pyvista` interpolate a surface from a cloud point? We can continue in a chat if you like (please tell me how to start one). Some data sets will yield an `Unable to factor linear system` warning/error, so it would be great to do Gaussian Splatting in that instance.